# Merged two DCIM folders by mistake

Tags: motorola-moto-g2

So I have a moto G, 2nd gen, I was transferring stuff from my internal memory to the SD card and my DCIM folder was also transferred by mistake and when the "Merge" option popped up, I clicked on "yes to all by mistake. I can't find most of my pictures now. Any way I can fix this now?

Comment: What steps did you take to move the files, and where are you looking for them now?

Comment: So I cut a few folders from my internal storage such as DCIM, video, etc. The SD card already had a folder by the name of DCIM which I didnt see. Then it asked me if I wanted to merge the folders and I said yes to all by mistake.

I'm practically looking everywhere for them now. :/

@DanHulme

Answer (score 0):

If they had the names like IMAG0001.jpg then the file from the first directory would have overwritten the second.

I have had files even on the same device have the same numbers, probably caused by me moving files around and screwing up its count.

Comment: Expecting such "auto-merge" options being user-friendly: shouldn't they warn on such occasions (a la "file with the same name exists..."), as any file explorer does? Are you sure they would overwrite files without asking?

Comment: Can you check if the file naming scheme for the two folders was the same? You might be able to determine the original folder from how the files are named.